# Gap in UITabBarController inside UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I have a root view of UINavigationController containing a UITabBarController.  The tab bar controller has two simple views.  When it first launches either in the iOS 6 simulator or on a device, a gap appears above the first view.  Switching to the second tab and back causes the gap to disappear.  This only started happening since iOS 6.  iOS 5 works just fine.  Any ideas what changed?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UIView *dummyView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [dummyView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UIViewController *dummyViewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [dummyViewController1 setView:dummyView1];

    UIView *dummyView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [dummyView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    UIViewController *dummyViewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [dummyViewController2 setView:dummyView2];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dummyViewController1, dummyViewController2, nil];

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    UINavigationController *rootNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:rootNavController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Just came across this myself seeing the issue only present in ios 7 builds not ios 8.  So apple must have realized this was a legitimate bug and fixed it themselves in ios 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple explicitly tells us in I believe the Application Programing Guide (or maybe the ViewController Guide) that a tabBarController should NOT be placed in a navigation controller. You need to reverse the order. You can play tricks with the tabBarController by switching its array of controllers, and having one set hide the tabBar. But any attempt to use the order as you have now is doomed to fail at some point - you may make it work in say iOS5.1, then see it break in 6, 6.1, or 7.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to reverse the order, Apple needs to explain why. I have looked all through their documentation and cannot find a sound reason to do this.

I can think of a very reasonable use of this configuration. Suppose I wanted to create an app that showed information in categories about a group of entities, say teams in a sports league. I could use the navigation controller as the enveloping controller and the tab bar to be displayed for each team for various kinds of stats such as team or player stats. Why would you do something like this any other way? It is perfectly logical. Other than to appease the gods at Apple of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure WHY they don't allow it or WHY 'the gap' happens, but I found a way around it:

```
tabController.SelectedIndex=1;
tabController.SelectedIndex=0;
```

After pushing the tab onto the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I found for this is to create the UINavigationController without a root controller, add it to the window, then push the UITabBarController:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[[self window] setRootViewController:navigationController];

[navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```